# Spring cache eviction with scheduled annotation

Tags: spring, spring-cache

In the following code cache works, but eviction does not work, could you approach me?
I have read following link:
[Schedule Spring cache eviction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42688020/schedule-spring-cache-eviction)

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CacheInvalidator {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000L)
    public void evictCache() {
       clearCache();
    }

    @CacheEvict(value = "count", allEntries = true)
    public void clearCache() {
    }
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ARepositoryImpl implements ARepository {

    @Cacheable(value = "count")
    public Integer count() {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("...", Integer.class);
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories
@EnableScheduling
@EnableCaching
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

in pom.xml:

```
   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because method `evictCache` in `CacheInvalidator` calls `clearCache` not on Spring's proxy but on original object and that method does nothing despite being annotated with `@CacheEvict(value = "count", allEntries = true)`.

Instead of:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CacheInvalidator {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000L)
    public void evictCache() {
       clearCache();
    }

    @CacheEvict(value = "count", allEntries = true)
    public void clearCache() {
    }
}
```

try:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CacheInvalidator {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000L)
    @CacheEvict(value = "count", allEntries = true)
    public void clearCache() {
    }

}
```